# LINQ to SQL filter by List<int>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

How can I retreive rows from table only when UserId is in my Users list ?

Code below doesnt work :/

```
List<int> selectedSourceUsers = ...
MyModelDataContext context = ...

e.Result = from u in context.Users
                   from id in selectedSourceUsers
                   where u.UserId == id
                   select u;
```

Thanks for help

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", you should say the error message or describe the unexpected behavior.

Comment: OK I will think about it in the future

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
int[] selectedUsersArray = selectedSourceUsers.ToArray();
e.Result = from u in context.Users
           where selectedUsersArray.Contains(u.UserId)
           select u;
```

(To be honest I'd have expected it to work with a `List<int>` as well, but using an array instead may fix it...)

Comment: doesnt work:

No translation for SQL Language for method „Boolean Contains(Int32)”.

I translated error from polish so it may sound different in original  verison

Comment: @snorlaks: Try converting the list to an `int[]` first. I'd expect that to work... I'll edit the answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Now it works but htere is an error:

You cant assign null value to member of type System.Int32 which is of type not nullable 


or sth like that :)

Comment: Sorry :)

It works correctly, my mistake was by calling ToList() method:

from u in context.Users.ToList()

I dont know why I have to create array to do such a simple task :/